# Xcode framework: Swift Generated Interface not in DerivedSources folder

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks, bridging-header

Xcode 10, iOS 12
I have a project, that has 2 targets: an app and a framework. I use both Swift and Objective-C. I'm trying to reference Swift classes from Objective-C. I've set the SWIFT_OBJC_INTERFACE_HEADER_NAME property to "SwiftInterface.h" in the project, and when the target is "app", all is working well, I can include and use Swift classes. With the same settings, the "framework" doesn't compile, because it can't find the generated header.

What I have investigated:

- The "app" generates the header file to {TempFolder}/{Project}.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.build/DerivedSources/SwiftInterface.h
- The "framework" has the corresponding folder, but the header file is missing.

I've read, that this might be because of Swift compiler errors, but it is not, since the file is actually generated in the MyFramework.framework/Headers folder, where the public headers are.

Now, if I copy this header file to the DerivedSources folder manually, the framework seems to compile normally.

So the question is: How can I make Xcode generate the swift bridging header to the right place, and how to remove it from the public headers folder.

Clean, Rebuild, DerivedData-Nuke didn't help.